# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to use MYSQL with Hibernate but getting issues in connecting to MYSQL database using hibernate.

Here are the steps I followed:

I ran below MYSQL commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE hibernate5;
USE hibernate5;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON hibernate5.* To 'hib5'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'hib';
```

Now I have created my hibernate.cfg.xml file as follows:

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate5</property>
    <property name="connection.username">hib5</property>
    <property name="connection.password">hib</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="org.hibernate.tutorials.Customer" />
</session-factory>
```

Now I wrote a simple program just to check if Hibernate is able to create table in MYSQL database or not:

```
public class AppTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                    .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Now when I run my AppTest.java program then I am getting error as:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.tutorial.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.tutorial.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at org.hibernate.tutorials.one.AppTest.main(AppTest.java:8)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.tutorial.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:27)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
    ... 28 more
```

Please help me where I am doing mistake?

I logged into MYSQL and checked variables for host and port using command `SHOW VARIABLES`, the port number is correct and set as its default value (3306), I used the hostname as mentioned in variables but even then I am facing same issue. I am able to run MYSQL on my command prompt with any issues.

Update:
I have given privileges to the newly created user also using below commands:

```
grant usage on *.* to hib5@localhost identified by 'hib'; 
grant all privileges on hibernate5.* to hib5@localhost;
```

Comment: did you flush privileges after creating the DB?

Comment: @Funtik, yes I have given all privileges to the new user, I have updated my post with the Grant commands I have used, please see.

Comment: yes, but you have to execute FLUSH PRIVILEGES; command after you've done your modifications

Comment: I ran the flush command, but still I am getting same error message.